# Why folders/files are not getting deployed onto test output folder while running unit tests on VS 2015?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, deployment, visual-studio-2015

Why folders are not getting deployed onto test output folder while running unit tests on VS 2015? 
When I open the same project in VS 2012 all required folders are getting deployed onto test output folder. I have .testsettings file in the project even then folders are not getting deployed. Do I have to change any settings in VS 2015 to deploy folders?

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx